# count unique words in string

Tags: php, string

`str_word_count` count all words into string. What is the way count unique words in string.

```
$string = "this is my my word with new word";
//echo count(str_word_count($string));  
echo str_word_count($string);
```

Here result is 8. But as there are only6 unique words, how to get that result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this may help you:

```
count(array_unique(str_word_count($str, 1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "this is my my word with new word";
//echo count(str_word_count($string));  
echo unique_word_count($string);

function unique_word_count($string) {
    $string = explode(' ', strtolower($string));
    $words = array_unique($string);
    return count($words);
}
```

I'd do it like the above.

Comment: Thinking about it, using $string = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", strtolower($string)); would be better but is a more costly on the time front.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will behave in the same way as the built-in str_word_count function however the results returned will be using unique words.  The only thing that is a bit different is in the case of using 2 for the format, in this case, the array returned will give the numeric position of the FIRST occurrence of the word in the string as the key.

```
    function str_word_count_unique($str = '', $format = 0, $charlist = NULL)
    {
        switch ($format) {
            case 0:
                return count(array_unique(str_word_count($str, 1, $charlist)));
                break;
            default:
                return array_unique(str_word_count($str, $format, $charlist));
                break;
        }
    }
```